# What is the name of this beautiful insect?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I spotted this magnificient looking insect last night in my house in Singapore. It was around 1.5 inches long and had a silverish golden back with long legs and antennae.

[image]

<sup>^ Click for full-size, higher-quality image</sup>

[image]

<sup>^ Click for full-size, higher-quality image</sup>

Comment: Pretty! You should add your location, that makes identification easier. (All i can say is that it's a heteropteran of some sort)

Comment: The presence of more than three veins in the forewing membrane (just barely visible in the top photo when magnified) and terrestrial habits narrows this to infraorder Pentatomorpha; the four-segmented antennae eliminate the superfamily Pentatomoidea; not knowing the local fauna forbids further progress from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a true bug ([Hemipteran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiptera)) in the infraorder [Pentatomomorpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatomomorpha). 
As Arthur Frost said in his [comment](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/74681/what-is-the-name-of-this-beautiful-insect#comment134606_74681), exact identification is difficult for those of us on the other side of the world.

However, a fortuitous series of internet [rabbit holes](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Internet%20rabbit%20hole) may have led me to a very similar looking specimen.

***Homoeocerus striicornis*** and ***Homoeocerus angulatus*** appear to be quite similar in appearance to your insect, and so I would not be surprised if your insect was at least in this genus (see [here](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/336010-Homoeocerus) for more pictures) within the "leaf-footed bugs" family ([Coreidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coreidae)).

- I'd say *Homoeocerus angulatus* is more likely only because the sightings maps on [inaturalist](https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/2916828) show this species being found in Singapore.

[image]

I can't say that any incredibly reputable or peer-reviewed resources in English online provide definitive support for this identification, but this is at least a step in the right (*a*?) direction.